# Frequency Response of a Stochastic Oscillator Numerically

Tags: computational-physics, oscillators, resonance, stochastic-processes

I am willing to obtain a frequency response plot for a stochastic oscillator governed by the following equation numerically.
$$
\ddot{x}+2\Gamma \dot{x}+\omega_{0}^{2}x=f(t)
$$
where $f(t)$ is a random force(modelled by gaussian white noise).

**Motivation**

I wanted to obtain the frequency response for a damped-driven oscillator given by the following.
$$
\ddot{x}+2\Gamma \dot{x}+\omega_{0}^{2}x=F\cos{\omega t}
$$
To do so, I solved the above differential equation for $x(t)$. Next, I obtained the power put into the system as $P(t)=F_{ext}\;\dot{x}=F\cos{(\omega t)}\;\dot{x}$. Finally, I plotted the average power over a cycle ($T=2\pi/\omega$) against the driving frequency, $\omega$.

I was able to do this successfully. I got a Lorentzian peaking at the natural frequency $\omega_{0}$.

I then wanted to replace the sinusoidal drive with a random one and obtain a frequency response. I can at best solve the stochastic differential equation for $x(t)$ but am not sure how to proceed next.

Comment: You can calculate the PSD for this system https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density